# Help with getting rid of circular dependency

Tags: design, c++, object-oriented-design, circular-dependency

I have the following circular dependency that I'd like to eliminate. I think I must have a flaw in my design. And I'd much appreciate any feedback on how to fix this.

My circular dependency comes from 3 important classes. `Worker`, `WorkingContext`, and `TaskManager`.

First, I have 2 `Worker` classes (`Worker`, and `WorkerGroup`). Each `Worker` is constructed with a `WorkingContext` object that stores state info.

```
class Worker 
{
    Worker(WorkingContext * context);
};

class WorkerGroup
{
};
```

Next, I have `WorkingContext`.

```
class WorkingContext
{
    // state info and various getters
    ...
    TaskManager * getTaskManager();
};
```

As shown, one of the things the `WorkingContext` stores is a `TaskManager`, which has a number of useful functions that depend on `Worker`. Here is a snippet

```
class TaskManager
{
    void assignCredit(Worker * worker, WorkerGroup * group, int credit);
    void revokeCredit(Worker * worker, int credit);
};
```

The circular dependency is that `Worker.h` needs to `#include "WorkingContext.h"`, which needs to `#include "TaskManager.h"`, which in turns needs to `#include "Worker.h"`.

Right now it works since I'm using forward reference, but that really is a last resort.

Comment: Forward references aren't a last resort. For this kind of sensible logical coupling, they are the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If Task Manager does not hold state, you can pull it out of Working Context and make all its function static.

Otherwise, considering how little i know from the snippet i can only guess what will be a good design, but it seems to me a worker should not contain (indirectly) a task manager.

If the design is as such that every worker has a state-full context object specific to it, this object is not the right container for a task manager API, especially as it seems that the task manager uses a worker and not the other way.

Try expressing the logical dependencies using "Has a" and "Uses a" relationships to better determine an appropriate hierarchy. Note that "Uses a" does not necessarily imply containment or ownership.

Comment: "task manager uses a worker, and not the other way". i'm not sure if that's right. maybe a better name for `taskmanager` would be `creditManager`. `worker` and `taskmanager` has a many to 1 relationship. each worker has 1 `CreditManager`. 1 `CreditManager` handles credit for many `worker`s. Before a `worker` actually does anything, it needs to first check with his `taskManager` if he has enough credits to do it. if not, he just exits. if he does, then he works, and then calls `revokeCredit`. maybe a better name for that would be `returnCredit` in any case, hope this is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

This design seems correct. In real life there are plenty of mutual dependencies like this.

As Sebastian pointed out in the comments, forward declaration of the classes are not a work around.  They are simply needed in case of mutual dependencies.  The only thing I'd change would be to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

You could however make the design more robust by using the [mediator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) to act as a kind of hub between the objects and to encapsulate the interactions between the different parts of the collaboration (see [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) the checklist and here an [example](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/mediator.aspx)). The consequence would be that `Worker`, `Workgroup` and `TaskManager` would not interact directly; each would only interact with the mediator.   Intuitively, your `WorkingContext` could be a good start for the concrete mediator.